# How to fix report opening app after test and then taking screenshot

Tags: java, testng, appium-android, extentreports

Trying to take a screenshot when the test fails. What is actually happening is once intellij gets to my @AfterMethod it launches the application again and takes a screenshot of the home screen.

I have tried putting the extent.flush(); into a @AfterMethod and changing the current @AfterMethod to an @AfterTest

```
    @AfterMethod
    public synchronized void afterMethod(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
        AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = MetricellTest.setupTests();
        String screenShot = CaptureScreenShot.captureScreen(driver, CaptureScreenShot.generateFileName(result));

        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            test.get().log(Status.FAIL, result.getName());
            test.get().log(Status.FAIL, result.getThrowable());
            test.get().fail("Screen Shot : " + test.get().addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShot));
            test.get().fail(result.getThrowable());
        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
            test.get().skip("Test Case : " + result.getName() + " has been skipped");
            test.get().skip(result.getThrowable());


        } else
            test.get().pass("Test passed");

        extent.flush();
    }

}
```

I expect it to take screenshots as it goes through and tests fail. Currently it just opens the application at the end of the test and takes a screenshot of the home screen.

Comment: Please add the code for your method `setupTests` as well so that we could get more clarity on the problem.

Comment: @SameerArora I have added the code the setupTests method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `@AfterMethod`, you are initialising the `driver` again and calling the `setupTests` method and your `setupTests` method is doing the initialisation of the app, because of which the app is getting opened again.

So, you need to make the following changes in your code and it would work fine then:

1. Declare the `AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver` globally instead of
   declaring it in the `setupTests` method, so that it can be used
   throughout the class.
2. Remove the line of code `AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver =
   MetricellTest.setupTests();` from your `@AfterMethod` because it is
   initialising the `driver` and the app again.

**Updated Answer and adding extra explanation:**
You can declare the `driver` globally like:
So, lets say your class name is `testClass`, you should declare the `driver` just after the code for the class is starting like:

```
public class testClass{
    AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    // Add Rest of the code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I declare the drvier globally?

Comment: @TomCockram have updated my answer, please check it now

Comment: Thanks, I've made those changes but I'm getting null pointer exception. I'm setting the driver like this ```public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> AppiumDriver = null;``` which I don't think is correct. How should I be doing it?

Comment: On which line you are getting NPE ?

Comment: Can you post your whole class code in the question after making the changes i suggested ? Would be able to help you better then

Comment: I've updated the classes. Unfortunately I can't remember how I got the null pointer exception. I'm getting cannot resolve symbol on the ```driver```. I have tried making it an AppiumDriver but that just provides different errors

Comment: @TomCockram i have seen your updated code, so as you have declared the driver globally, you dont need to declare it inside the `setupTests()` method as well. So please remove the line `AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;` from inside your `setupTests()` method and everything should work fine

Comment: Still leaves my driver with 'cannot resolve symbol driver'. Changing it to ```AppiumDriver``` gives me an 'Expression expected' error

Comment: Please declare the driver as `public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;` globally and not like the one you have used.

Comment: I have changed that. Drivers inside the class where I declare the driver work but trying to use the driver in a different class doesn't work. Do I need to declare the driver in each class that I want to use it?

Comment: either you need to pass the driver or you can use that driver by calling by using `className.driver` here `className` is the class where you have initialised it

Comment: I have added ```public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;``` into my class where I'm trying to take a screenshot. I'm getting a 'nullpointerexception' on this line ```String screenShot = CaptureScreenShot.captureScreen(driver, CaptureScreenShot.generateFileName(result));```

Comment: What is the class name where you have written this line `public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;` ?

Comment: The class name is ```ExtentTestNGReportBuilder```. This is the class where my @AfterMethod lives. I have just added the whole reportbuilder class to my original question.

Comment: No i am asking the class name where `public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;` line of code is present.

Comment: It is present in my class ```MetricellTest``` where the ```setupTests();``` method lives and now the report builder.

Comment: Ok, so you need to do two things now. 1. Remove `public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;` from your class `ExtentTestNGReportBuilder` 2. Use `String screenShot = CaptureScreenShot.captureScreen(MetricellTest.driver, CaptureScreenShot.generateFileName(result));` in your `ExtentTestNGReportBuilder` class instead of the line you are using there

Comment: Thanks very much. It's now taking screenshots of the application! Not quite when I want them like it just took a screenshot when the test passed. Also it's not adding it to the report but it the original question is now solved!

Comment: Great thanks, please revert the question to the original one for the future readers